# Send a stream of data fetched from a url as http respone in ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, stream, sinatra

I am building a web application using sinatra. It basically takes a url of a page as request and fetches the link to media file from the page. Once that is retrieved it opens a stream to the media file. Now I want to send this stream as http response to client. I tried to do the following.

```
get '/' do
  url=PM.link(params[:url])
  puts url
  buf=nil
  open(url, 'rb') do |rf|
    while(buf=rf.read(1024)) do
      stream do |out|
        out << buf
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

and also this

```
get '/' do
  url=PM.link(params[:url])
  puts url
  buf=nil
  open(url, 'rb') do |rf|
    stream do |out|
      out.write rf.read
    end  
  end
end
```

But neither work. I tried storing the media file in a local file it stores it properly. But when I try to write it to out stream it responds with no data. Am I missing something? Or sinatra doesn't allow writing binary from one stream to other.

Comment: Are you using a web server that supports streaming? Or are you perhaps using Shotgun? The Sinatra docs say the following: "Note that the streaming behavior, especially the number of concurrent requests, highly depends on the web server used to serve the application. Some servers, like WEBRick, might not even support streaming at all. If the server does not support streaming, the body will be sent all at once after the block passed to stream finishes executing. Streaming does not work at all with Shotgun."

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you aren't making the request properly. To make an `http request` do this:

```
uri = URI.parse(yoururl)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
```

Then you can do what you want with the response. In your case it might look like this:

```
get '/' do
  url=PM.link(params[:url])
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  response = http.request(request)

end
```

However, this won't work for streaming. Here is a tutorial that should help you out: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/5/24/building-streaming-rest-apis-with-ruby#